# Turn a gradient image to a footer

Tags: css

How do I turn a gradient image to a footer? I want to turn this upside down and make it into a bottom gradient http://lab.desilence.net/cinemascreen_test/gradient_red.png. I downloaded the image as a png but it doesn't show up on the web page.

```
#footer{
    z-index:1;
    width:100%;
    height:25px;
/*  background-color:#FA1414;*/
    float:left;
    background-image:url('gradient_red.lnk');

}
```

Instead of opening up the image like it does with other images on the site, opening the file in my text editor (Eclipse for PHP) shows one line of squares and odd symbols and is listed as gradient_red.lnk instead of gradient_red.png. Any ideas what's going wrong?

Cool, that's working. How do I shrink the image so it's small enough to be a footer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well,

i would suggest you download the image once again.

Just drag'n'drop out of your prefered browser into Eclipse.

Then it should show up as `*.png` and not as `*.lnk`, which in general indicates a link.

Answer (score 1):

well, you have ".Ink" set as your file extension in your CSS man.... Try changing it to ".png"

Answer (score 1):

.lnk is the file extension for a shortcut. You're trying to use a shortcut to a file as a background-image. Use the png instead.